# Redirect from .com/ to just .com

Tags: python, django

I have a web page served by Django, and i want to make it to 301 redirect from 
    `mysite.com/`    to    `mysite.com`    without a slash on the end. Is it possible to do with Django? 
Last version of Django, python 3.6.

path("", views.home, name="main_page")

Changing nginx config is not an option at my server

Comment: What happens now when you type in `/` as a path?

Comment: Both pages `mysite.com` and `mysite.com/` return code 200 and same content. My friend said that SEO is better when there is no 2 same pages, i dont even know if thats correct :D Also have to add that changing nginx settings is not an option on my current server.

Comment: they are the same :) your friend is incorrect about his assumption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysite.com/` and `mysite.com` are the same URL. You don't need to set up a redirect.

Your friend probably means that you shouldn't have the same content for `mysite.com/foo` and `mysite.com/foo/`.

In Django, you would usually achieve this by using the URL `foo/`, then the default setting `APPEND_SLASH = True` will redirect `/foo` to `/foo/`.

Comment: Oh, i suspected that most likely he is wrong. He explicitly said that about main page. So nothing wrong with my setup. Thanks a lot!